# How do we prove that $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}\mathrm{d}x$ equals $\arcsin(2x - 1) + C$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

My friend and I were looking at MIT Integration Bee problems, and we both tried to solve $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}dx$$ However, we both got differing answers and he won't tell me how he got his.

I did the following:

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}dx=\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-1}}dx$$
$$Let\space u=\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-1}\Longleftrightarrow du=\frac{-1}{2x^2\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-1}}dx$$
$$x=\frac{1}{u^2+1}$$

$$-2\int\frac{1}{u^2+1}du=-2\arctan{u}+C=-2\arctan({\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-1}})+C$$

My friend got the answer as

$$\arcsin({2x-1})+C$$

I haven't been able to figure out how he arrived at his answer. Can they show me how he might have gotten his answer? Thank you.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yeah, I guess I know that both answers are right.  I'll edit my original question to clarify that.  My main question is how he got his answer with arcsin(x) vs my method which got arctan(x), even though both are the same.

Comment: He told me "Too bad figure it out yourself" 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is how he obtained the proposed result:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x - x^{2}}} & = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1/4 - (x - 1/2)^{2}}}\\\\
& = \int\frac{2\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1 - (2x - 1)^{2}}}\\\\
& = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}(2x - 1)}{\sqrt{1 - (2x - 1)^{2}}}\\\\
& = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{1 - u^{2}}}\\\\
& = \arcsin(u) + c\\\\
& = \arcsin(2x - 1) + c
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Ohhhhh he completed the square!  I can't believe I didn't remember that!  Thank you

Comment: @TreeGuy you are welcome! I am glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest solution would be to recognize the hidden chain rule:

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x-x^2}} = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}\cdot\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\sqrt{x})^2}}\cdot 2d(\sqrt{x}) = 2\arcsin\sqrt{x}$$

Plotting the difference of each of these solutions, we can see that [your solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2arcsin%28sqrt%28x%29%29+%2B+2+%5Carctan%28%5Csqrt%281%2Fx+-+1%29%29) and [your friend's solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2arcsin%28sqrt%28x%29%29+-+arcsin%282x-1%29) both give constants on the domain of the original integrand, $(0,1)$, meaning all solutions are correct.

Comment: This is another cool solution neither of us thought of!  Turns out he completed the square for $x-x^2$

Answer (score 0):

Letting $x=\sin^2 \theta$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I=\int\frac{d x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}} &=\int\frac{2 \sin \theta \cos \theta d \theta}{\sin \theta \cos \theta} =2 \theta=2\arcsin \sqrt x +C
\end{aligned}
$$